# Can't add account in the Xbox live for Test account results is error

Tags: xbox-live

When I Added Account for Authorize Xbox Live accounts in the partner center, Is appear the error

"400 - - Account 61379360-73a7-4bc4-a1fd-1d10b3783d8e with type Managed tried to access API for account type Open."

how can I fix this?